# SIMPLIS (Elements version) - PWL Topologies Error Dialog Box = Annoying

Tags: power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, simulation

Within the free version of SIMPLIS, there is an example "LLC_HALF_BRIDGE_CONVERTER". I can't seem to share the file, but it's free and anyone who downloads SIMPLIS has access to it. The schematic is below:

[image]

When you press F11, there are some parameters you can play with, like Lr, Lp, N, and the deadtime. I'm finding that when I play with the parameters the circuit is quite sensitive and will error out quite easily (see below)

[image]

How to reduce the number of PWL topologies? Why changing the deadtime (or other parameters) changes the number of PWL topologies? What exactly are PWL topologies? Any extra information would be great. Thank you!

Comment: You've reached the limit of the free version and there is not much you can do with a complicated circuit as the one shown. A topology is when a new linear structure is explored during simulation and Elements limits the number of these topologies. Check my 120+ [ready-made templates](http://powersimtof.com/Downloads/Book/Christophe%20Basso%20SIMPLIS%20Collection.pdf), there are a few LLCs which run on the free demo. Also, you may want to check this presentation on LLC [control methods](http://powersimtof.com/Downloads/PPTs/Introduction%20to%20the%20LLC%20Converter.pdf).

Comment: Mr. Basso, I was hoping you would respond! Can you dive a deeper into what you mean when you say linear structure? So, for instance, let's say you run the circuit and it successfully compiles. Then, you change the deadtime, and you exceed the PWL topologies limit. In my mind, it should still run, since the characteristic equations that describe the topology haven't changed, and assuming you haven't gone from CCM to DCM or BCM (so, mode transition), the only thing that has changed it is a single parameter. Tell me where I'm wrong, please :)

Comment: With pleasure *RogerDodger* : ) I looked a bit into the way SIMPLIS operates in the [seminar](http://powersimtof.com/Downloads/PPTs/Simulating%20with%20SIMPLIS%20-%20Rev%200.21.pdf) I built but the way the engine works is quite secretive and I don't have more details. The fact that you changed the deadtime may force the program to transitions through more topologies for finding steady-state, for instance, if ZVS is lost because DT is too small or if the voltage rings because it is too large. I believe the circuit was originally tweaked to exactly meet the demo version limit : )